# How to add NTLM auth to .net core when app could be self hosted or IIS

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, iis, asp.net-core

I have a .net core application that needs to use NTLM authentication.
If I use the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.HttpSys`

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .UseStartup<Startup>()
       .UseHttpSys(options =>{
                              options.Authentication.Schemes =  AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
                              options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
                             }).Build()
```

It will work great if I self host, but if it's deployed on IIS, it will crash.

Same difference if I don't use it and use IIS settings to provide windows auth, if I need to run self hosted it will crash.

Is there anyway to make one executable that will work for both scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but this solution is a little shady.

There is a setting indicating if IIS is providing authentication. But that setting is keyed by a constant that is marked internal. So you can access it, if you hard code the magic string `"IIS_HTTPAUTH"`.

```
var webhost = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                     .UseStartup<Startup>();
//If not hosted by IIS for auth
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(webhost.GetSetting("IIS_HTTPAUTH"))) {
    webhost = webhost.UseHttpSys(options => {
                            options.Authentication.Schemes =  AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
                            options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
                       });
}
return webhost.Build();
```

Current as of **.netcore2.0.X**

Comment: There are a a few different environment variables this trick works with. This is one of the newer ones.